# Android - how to pass data to application startup code (i.e. onCreate)

Tags: android

I have an interesting use case where I need to pass certain data to my application so that it can be used in its "attachBaseContext" method.

I know that typically, the proper way to pass data to an application is to use an intent and pass the data through to an "activity" but this is too late in my application's life cycle.  I need the data in my application so that I can use it to setup the environment *prior* to any android components running (e.g. Activities, Services, ContentProviders, etc.).

At the moment, I use a very hack-ish approach where I write the data to my application's internal storage and then read it in my "attachBaseContext".  I am hoping there is a better way though to do this as this doesn't seem very safe/clean.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying that you have an `Application` subclass that overrides `attachBaseContext()`? Also, how is this data "passed"?

Comment: Yup, that's correct.  I have an application class that extends "Application" and currently have an override for "attachBaseContext".  My application is multi-process.  I have my "primary" process spawn off children processes.  I would like my "primary" process to pass data to the chilldren processes.  At the moment, I am using files to do this.  My primary application/process writes data in a file, and the children application/process read it.  I was hoping there was something cleaner.

Comment: Where does that data originally come from? Is it hardcore, for instance?

Comment: No, the primary application determines this at runtime and the information changes. I am not sure if it matters but it uses a service to create the children processes. In my manifest, I've defined services with the "process" attribute set to different values.  To create the process , I just invoke bindservice from my primary application.